# Can't send message to specific room[socket.io]

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to send message to specific room (all clients in room), I have searched a lot and tried these options:

```
        io.in(socket.RoomId).emit('Test');
        io.to(socket.RoomId).emit('Test');        
        io.sockets.in(socket.RoomId).emit('Test');
```

I wanted to send as a server, so without using an existing socket in the room. But because I could not find a way I tried the following:

```
this.ListOfSockets[0].to(RoomId).emit('Test');
```

This worked not, so I tried to just emit to the socket itself like this:

```
this.ListOfSockets[0].emit('Test');
```

And this was working as I expected.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I send as a server to all the clients in a specific room?

**Update 2:**
Adding some more code for li X

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

console.log('client connected');
playerCount++;

//For testing purposes I give player random generated string using: var shortid = require('shortid');
socket.id = shortid.generate();
console.log('id of this socket is:' + socket.id);

//When client decides to play the game and want's to join a random room
socket.on('JoinRoom', function () 
{
    //Checks if there exist an open room
    if(OpenRoom.length > 0)
    {
        //Joins first room in openroom list
        socket.join(OpenRoom[0].RID);
        socket.RoomId = OpenRoom[0].RID;

        //Joinedroom lets player open the next scene in my game
        socket.emit('JoinedRoom');

        //Joinedroom is a function that sends information to the socket about the room and the state of the game,
        //adding the the player to room etc.
        JoinedRoom(socket.id, OpenRoom[0].RID, socket);
    }
    else
    {
        //If there is no open room, it creates a new room with new id.
        OpenRoom.push({ RID:shortid.generate(), TimeOutID: null });
        //Joins room
        socket.join(OpenRoom[OpenRoom.length - 1].RID);
        socket.RoomId = OpenRoom[OpenRoom.length - 1].RID;

        //Creates room and fills information to it
        socket.emit('JoinedRoom');
        var NewRoom = new Room(OpenRoom[OpenRoom.length - 1].RID)
        NewRoom.addPlayer(socket.id);
        NewRoom.addSocket(socket);

        Rooms.push(NewRoom);

        OpenRoom[OpenRoom.length - 1].TimeOutID = setTimeout(CloseRoom, 5000, OpenRoom[OpenRoom.length - 1]);
    }

    //Checking if RoomId exists, it exists.
    console.log(socket.RoomId);

    //When I send 'test' to client, the client should print 'Succesfully Tested' to the console

    //For io.to I dont get the message 'Succesfully Tested'
    io.to(socket.RoomId).emit('Test');

    //With socket.emit I get 'Succesfully Tested' message inside my console at the client side.
    socket.emit('Test');

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you log `OpenRoom[OpenRoom.length - 1].RID` what occurs at each point?

Comment: `socket.join(OpenRoom[OpenRoom.length - 1].RID);` Also should this not be `socket.join(OpenRoom[OpenRoom[0]].RID);` If your not adding to it?

Comment: Yea after you mentioned it I have changed it to 0. At lot I get at every stage the same ID, so that must be working good. Can it be wrong at client side? This is my code at client side: socket.On ("Test", onTest); (is C# code for unity game engine)

Comment: You'll need to use `socket.On('Test', data =>{ //code here})` Within this you can make the call to your function `onTest` and pass the necessary information via data.

Comment: @Saut Alkan I hope my answer has helped you out here, let me know if it still isn't working!

Comment: Same result 'socket.emit('Test')' works, 'io.to(socket.RoomId).emit('Test')' doesn't work. I am thinking to take contact with the maker of socket.io plugin for unity game engine. Maybe io.to is not supported by some way? Thanks for your help li x!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default all sockets are joined to there own personal room when the socket.id is derived but to create sepereate rooms you'll need to call `socket.join('foo');` on the socket's which you wish to become part of a room.

Then after which you'll be able to send message's to the room using `io.to('foo').emit('test');` Also note that you can also add `broadcast` between `io.` and `.to` which will allow you to send a message to all sockets  **except**  the socket who made the call.

`socket.join(OpenRoom[OpenRoom.length - 1].RID);`
 Also this should be 
`socket.join(OpenRoom[OpenRoom[0]].RID);`

You'll need to use `socket.On('Test', data =>{ //code here})` Within this you can make the call to your function onTest and pass the necessary information via data.

Comment: Hi Li, thanks for explanation, but I already am joined a separate room. This is the code: socket.join(OpenRoom[OpenRoom.length - 1].RID);
 socket.RoomId = OpenRoom[OpenRoom.length - 1].RID; I add the room id to socket.RoomId and use the RoomId to send message to the room but without succes.

Comment: If you could edit this into your question I'll do some testing once you've added it as code :-)

Comment: Thanks @lix,  my problem is not solved but I think the problem is at the plugin I use for unity game engine, I am going to take contact with him to solve the problem. Thanks for all your guidance and help!